# How to perform calculation with cumulative sum using ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

Is it possible to perform an arbitrary calculation (eg. `A2*B2`) on a set of rows *and* obtain the cumulative sum along the way using `ARRAYFORMULA`? For example, in the following sheet we have numbers (column A), multipliers (column B), the result of multiplying them (column C), and a cumulative tally (column D):

```
  | A       B           C       D           E                F
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | number  multiplier  result  cumulative  array formula    array formula sum?
2 | 3       4           12      12          12  
3 | 2       4           8       20          8   
4 | 10      1           10      30          10  
5 | 7       9           63      93          63
```

I can use `ARRAYFORMULA` in cell `E2` (specifically, `ARRAYFORMULA(A2:A5*B2:B5)`) to do the multiplication. Is it possible to use `ARRAYFORMULA` (or alternative tool) in cell `F2` to show the cumulative total?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))*A2:A*B2:B), SIGN(B2:B))))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: That works. It is pretty slow with an open ended range, but if I need to operate over a smaller number of rows I can cap the range (ie. `A2:A10`,  instead of `A2:A`) and it is quite fast. Thanks @player0.

Comment: Would love an explanation for how this thing actually works?

Comment: @FloatingRock `TRANSPOSE((ROW(A2:A)<=
 TRANSPOSE(ROW(A2:A)))` will create a table of TRUE/FALSE (which is 1/0 after multiplication) in a such way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QkD86.png then with 1/0 also A and B columns are multiplied. this is then inserted into `MMULT` which performs sum of columns per each row. `SIGN` will return column of ones and `IF` statement with  `A2:A="",,` will ensure that empty rows are nullified (visually)

Answer (score 4):

Calculate the cumulative sum with the [SCAN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094) and [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) functions:

`=SCAN(0, F5:F, LAMBDA(accumulated_value, cell_value, accumulated_value + cell_value))`

This will run faster as it runs with linear complexity (`O(N)`) compared to the `ARRAYFORMULA` solution, which runs in quadratic time (`O(N**2)`).

Where:

- `0` is the initial value of the cumulative sum
- `F5:F` is the range to sum over
- `LAMBDA(accumulated_value, cell_value, accumulated_value + cell_value))` is the function that calculates the sum at each cell

[Sample File](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16GpTmSV9YA0UZTcEiprgiXjQXsDYrg2HIohYX-uiApo/edit#gid=841995834)

Comment: This is the fastest solution!